# How to actually use has_many :through and set up relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, has-many-through

So many tutorials on how to set up a `has_many :through` but not enough on how to actually do it!

I have a `Inventories` and `Requests` table joined by `Bookings`. Example: there could be 3 lenders who have tents in inventory, each of which is requested by 3 other borrowers. What I want to do is for each of the 3 tents in inventory, show that lender the list of 3 borrowers who requested the tent. Then the lender can pick who s/he wants to be the ultimate borrower.

I have thoughts on how this should work, but no idea if it's right, so please give advice on the below! The action is driven all by the `Requests` controller. Let's run through an example where the `Inventories` table already has 3 tents, ids `[1, 2, 3]`. Let's say Borrower Pat submits a `Request_ID 1` for a tent.

1. Am I then supposed to create 3 new `Bookings` all with `Request_ID 1` and then `Inventory_ID [1, 2, 3]` to get all the conceivable combinations? Something like

   `Inventory.where(name: "tent").each { |inventory| @request.bookings.create(inventory_id: inventory.id) }`
2. And then is it right to use the `Bookings` primary key as the foreign key in both the `Request` and `Inventory`? Which means that after Borrower Pat submits his request, the `bookings_id` will be blank until say Lender 2 accepts, at which point `bookings_id` equals the id that matches the combination of `Request_ID 1` and `Inventory_ID 2`
3. Now let's say when a `Request` is posted and a `Bookings` is made, I email the lender. However, I realized I don't want to bother Lender Taylor if 3 borrowers want her tent over the same time period. I'll just email her the first time, and then the subsequent ones she'll find out about when she logs in to say yes or no. In this situation is it OK to just query the `Bookings` table in the create action, something like (expanding off above)

-

```
Inventory.where(name: "tent").each do |inventory| 
  if !Bookings.find_by_inventory_id(inventory.id).exists?
    # If there are no other bookings for this inventory, then create the booking and send an email
    @request.bookings.create(inventory_id: inventory.id)
    AlertMail.mail_to_lender(inventory).deliver
  else
    # If there are other bookings for this inventory, do any of those bookings have a request ID where the requested time overlaps with this new request's requested time? If so then just create a booking, don't bother with another email  
    if Bookings.where(inventory_id: inventory.id).select { |bookings_id| Bookings.find_by_id(bookings_id).request.time overlaps_with current_request.time }.count > 0 
      @request.bookings.create(inventory_id: inventory.id)
    # If there are other bookings for this inventory but without overlapping times, go ahead and send an new email
    else
      @request.bookings.create(inventory_id: inventory.id)
      AlertMail.mail_to_lender(inventory).deliver
    end
  end
end
```

Code above is probably flawed, I just want to know the theory of how this is supposed to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a poor job of asking this question. What I wanted to know was how to create the actual associations once everything is set up in the DB and Model files.

If you want to create a record of B that is in a many-to-many relationship with an existing record of A, it's the same syntax of `A.Bs.create`. What was more important for me, was how to link an A and B that already existed, in which case the answer was `A.B_ids += B_id`.

Two other things:

1. More obvious: if you created/ linked something one way, was the other way automatic? And yes, of course. In a many-to-many relationship, if you've done say `A.B_ids += B_id`, you no longer have to do 'B.A_ids += A_id`.
2. Less obvious: if A and B are joined by table AB, the primary key of table AB doesn't need to be added to A or B. Rails wants you to worry about the AB table as less as possible, so searches, builds, etc. can all be done by `A.B` or `B.A` instead of `A.AB.B` or `B.AB.A`

Answer (score 1):

**Join Table**

Firstly, [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) works by using a *join table* - a central table used to identify two different [`foreign_keys`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) for your other tables. This is what provides the `through` functionality:

[image]

Some trivia for you:

- `has_and_belongs_to_many` tables are called `[plural_model_1]_[plural_model_2]` and the models *need* to be in alphabetical order (`entries_users`)
- `has_many :through` join tables can be called anything, but are typically called `[alphabetical_model_1_singular]_[alphabetical_model_2_plural]`

--

**Models**

The `has_many :through` models are generally constructed as such:

```
#app/models/inventory.rb
Class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :bookings
   has_many :requests, through: :bookings
end

#app/models/booking.rb
Class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :inventory
   belongs_to :request
end

#app/models/request.rb
Class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :bookings
   has_many :requests, through: :bookings
end
```

--

**Code**

Your code is really quite bloated - you'll be much better doing something like this:

```
#app/controllers/inventories_controller.rb
Class InventoriesController < ApplicationController
   def action
      @tents = Inventory.where name: "tent"
      @tents.each do |tent|
          booking = Booking.find_or_create_by inventory_id: tend.id
          AlertMail.mail_to_lender(tent).deliver if booking.is_past_due?
      end
   end
end

#app/models/booking.rb
Class Booking < ActiveRecord::Base
   def is_past_due?
      ...logic here for instance method
   end
end
```

Used [`find_or_create_by`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by)

You should only be referencing things once - it's called [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself) (don't repeat yourself)

Comment: Thanks!!! So just to be clear, the primary key of the Bookings join table is indeed supposed to be the foreign key that is then referenced on the Inventory and Request tables? And in my case if 3 borrowers request 3 of the same things, I will have 9 bookings records, one for each possible combination. Is that right? I get the diagram and everything, it's the keys that are really messing me up.